# Error:Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:_debugAnnotationProcessor' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-kenburnsview

> Gradle Project Refresh Failed

After I added [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView) Library to `build.gradle` on app level. When I try to sync the gradle it failed.

**build.gradle** (app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.ac"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0_dev"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'

//ButterKnife for view injector
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

// EventBus for passing data between activities and fragments
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

//Material Loading Circular Progress Bar with white background
compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'

//GSON for parsing JSON into Java Object and vice versa
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

//For Image Loading from network
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

//SLiding up Panel Layout for Music Player
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'

//For Network Calling
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

//ViewPagerIndicator
compile 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:0.0.7'

//Google Play Services
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.0'

//Ken Burns Effect for Image Background
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'

//Material Search View
// compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
compile project(':searchlibrary')

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle** (project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Are you facing the same problem ?

Comment: I get the same error message but when trying to add a different library, I think it's something to do with Jack

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I got it when trying to add a dependency to "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4" for an android training class.

I managed to get past it and it did involve Jack, as @Scott suspected.

Got past it by:

1. commenting out the added dependency, the jackOptions enable true block, and the compileOptions block, where I had it compatible with 1.8.
2. Sync/Clean/Rebuild Gradle (whichever it is, I'm still learning)
3. Uncomment the added dependency, sync/rebuild gradle again
4. Uncomment the jackOptions and compileOptions blocks, sync/rebuild gradle again

At that point, it worked for me.

Comment: That I can't say, unfortunately.  I'm not familiar with what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I was able to get past the problem by simply removing jackOptions and compileOptions from the app level Gradle file, sync/build then add back in and sync/build.  Jack does offer some good features, but I'm getting tired of it being temperamental especially with libraries like Dagger 2 (for which I have include the complete Guava library otherwise I receive NoMethodFound error when compiling).

Answer (score 6):

Add it to app build.gradle or project build.module:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

I get this problem when I add 'constraint-layout' dependency and I find out answer in ofical manual: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html
I think it will help you!

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trying everything, this worked for me -> Upgrade `com.google.gms:google-services` to latest version.
Case : added

```
dataBinding {
   enabled = true
}
```

Solution : In project **gradle classpath** changed

> 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'

to

> 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' (latest version)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I upgraded gradle and a google-play-services lib and didn't realize that you are apparently required to remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of app module's `build.gradle`.
Removing it solved this for me.</strike>

The docs were a little misleading. Removing `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` did indeed solve this problem, but the line is still required for Firebase to work actually.
After some more playing around, I noticed that also removing the `dataBinding{enabled true}` made the error go away. But again, also this is not a solution.
In the end I had to downgrade to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` - which again is obviously not a solution because you are missing out on e.g. InstantRun, but at least it builds.
The whole issue was introduced after an update to Android Studio 3.1.2, so I assume that downgrading again would solve it.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I come across this question too , i added maven in repositories{...} and a dependency in dependencies {...} of module's build.gradle .

I find the reason , because Android Studio can't load the dependency from maven repository . then instead compile, i copy the jar to module , sync ,the error is disappeared.

In summary , you can check out the dependency is loaded or not at "C:\Users\wjj.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1".

I hope it can help you!